# Twilio update webhook for number by python code

Tags: python, twilio

Is there any way to set webhook url for Twilio number by python code ??

something as: client.number('MY_TWILIO_NUMBER').update(webhook='ngrok.io')

???
I want make automate update when i start new ngrok instance

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here. You can accomplish this [via the Twilio CLI](https://www.twilio.com/docs/twilio-cli/general-usage#webhooks) as well as [with Python using Twilio Incoming Phone Numbers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource?code-sample=code-update-incomingphonenumber-to-use-a-new-voice-url&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=7.x)! That Python code would look something like this (replacing the variables with your own account SID, auth token, and the phone number SID you'd like to use which can be found in the Console or via the CLI):

```py
import os
from twilio.rest import Client

# Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
# and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

incoming_phone_number = client \
    .incoming_phone_numbers('PNXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') \
    .update(voice_url='https://www.your-new-voice-url.com/example')

print(incoming_phone_number.friendly_name)
```

Let me know if this helps at all!